# How am I computing $\int \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 9}}dx$ incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \displaystyle\int \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 9}}dx$

doing a trig sub:

$x = 3\tan(\theta)$

$dx = 3\sec^{2}(\theta)d\theta$

$\displaystyle\int \frac{(3\tan(\theta))^{3}}{\sqrt{3\tan(\theta)^{2} + 9}}d\theta$

$\displaystyle\int \frac{ ( 27\tan^{3}(\theta) } { \sqrt{ 3\tan(\theta)^{2} + 9 } }d\theta$

$27\displaystyle\int \frac{\tan^{3}(\theta)\cdot\sec^{2}(\theta)}{\sqrt{\sec^{2}(\theta)}}d\theta$

$27\displaystyle\int \tan(\theta)\cdot\tan(\theta)\cdot\sec(\theta)\cdot d(\theta)$

Got stuck here and think I am doing this wrong.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: Your approach looks fine. Keep in mind the pythagorean identity for tan and sec, and this is a solvable integral. Not easy by any means, but solvable.

Comment: There don't need to be bounds @TheGreatDuck...it's indefinite.
Careful to replace the $dx$ with $3\sec^2(\theta)d \theta$ in the first integral after the substitution.

Comment: Here are a few errors: $x^2=9\tan^2(\theta)$ (but you have another error later, so it doesn't matter), and somehow, you lose a $\tan(\theta)$ in the last step. Now, in the last step, you can replace $\tan^2(\theta)$ again and hopefully recognize what is in front of you.
Or you might consider the substitution $u=x^2+9$ instead for your integral.

Comment: Also, you might consider using `\tan` for $\tan$ and `\sec` for $\sec$ and `\cdot` for $\cdot$ (multiplication).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that I lost that tan so then now I can do a trig integral: tan^{2}(x)*tan(x)*sec(x)*dx and that to (sec^{2} - 1)*tan(x)*sec(x)dx and then u-sub that (u^2 - 1) take the integral 27 [ sec^{3}(x) / 3 - sec(x) ] creating a triangle I get: 1/9( √(9+x^2) / 3)^3 ) - 27( √(9+x^2) / 3 ) + C .... Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Made a mistake there. In that first 27 it would cancel with 3 making 9, then with that left over the the 9 would divide with the 3^3 of the denominator of the first parens. so 1/3 there.

Comment: Seems good. In any case, the substitution $u=x^2+9$ is much easier (unless you really want to use trig. substitution). Note that also in comments you can use MathJax and this makes it much more readable.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Will keep that in mind for when I type math next. Thanks to everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
 \int u dv = uv - \int v du
$$

$$
  u = x^{2}, \qquad dv = \frac{x }{\sqrt{x^{2}+9}}dx
$$
$$
  du = 2x dx, \qquad v = \sqrt{x^{2}+9}
$$

---

$$
  \int \frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+9}}dx = \frac{1}{3} \left(x^2-18\right) \sqrt{x^2+9}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct except that the last step is wrong. It can be fixed and completed as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { Let } x=3 \tan \theta \quad d x=3 \sec ^2 \theta d \theta\\
&I=\int \frac{27 \tan ^2 \theta\cdot 3 \sec ^2 \theta d \theta}{\sqrt{9 \tan ^2 \theta+9}}\\
&=27 \int \tan ^3 \theta \sec \theta d \theta\\
&=27 \int \tan ^2 \theta d(\sec \theta)\\
&=27 \int\left(\sec ^2 \theta-1\right) d(\sec \theta)\\
&=27\left(\frac{\sec ^3 \theta}{3}-\sec \theta\right)\\
&=9 \sec \theta\left(\sec ^2 \theta-3\right)+C\\&=9 \sec \theta\left(\tan ^2 \theta-2\right)+C\\&= \frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{3}\left(x^2-18\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

---

One more quicker method is **integration by parts**.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+9}} d x &=\int x^2 d\left(\sqrt{x^2+9}\right) \\
&=x^2 \sqrt{x^2+9}-\int \sqrt{x^2+9} d\left(x^2\right) \\
&=x^2 \sqrt{x^2+9}-\frac{2}{3}\left(x^2+9\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C \\
&=\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{x^2+9}\left(3 x^2-2 x^2-18\right)+C \\
&=\frac{1}{3}\left(x^2-18\right) \sqrt{x^2+9}+C
\end{aligned}
$$